# Is any company offering cheap drive space (in the cloud?) with user uploaded files being publicly accessible at a URL without a log in?

Tags: cloud-storage

Is any company offering cheap drive space (in the cloud?) allowing user uploaded files to be publicly accessible at a URL without a log in? I want to control what content is uploaded. But I want anyone to be able to access it. I'm aware that I can also do so by owning a web domain / website. Wondering if there is a cheaper way.  I've searched cloud-storage and such, but I'm finding it hard to find a service offering that specific capability.

Comment: For total flexibility, you will probably need a website.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta posts on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) // [Are questions for service providers welcome at our site?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/185) // [Are mail service offering recommendations on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2733/185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Drive.

**This gives you a readonly link**

1. Create a folder
2. Right Click and select Share
3. At the bottom is `General Access`, change the dropdown to `Anyone with link`
4. Leave the second dropdown as `Viewer`
5. Share the link

**Upload Link**

Repeat the process with another folder and mark it `Editor` instead of `Viewer`.  Share this link for uploading files.

Comment: Very nice, Rohit.  Just the thing.  Google in so many ways is a class act.  Brought the world to our doorsteps with Search (turned the world into a virtual brain).  And that's just the start.

Comment: I would have mentioned Google Drive, too. However, if you're desparate, you can always enarmor your file into plaintext and post it on pastebin, a forum, or something. You can use GNU Privacy Guard to enarmor files.